# dataTable column searching gives undefined error

Tags: jquery, datatables

I use dataTables to show data rendered from the server.

```
var dtable = $( "#oolt_control_body" ).find( "#product-list" ).dataTable({
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "iDisplayLength": 25,
    "aoColumnDefs": [
      { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 0 ] }
     ]
});

$("#product-list tfoot th").each( function ( i ) {
        var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
            .appendTo( $(this).empty() )
            .on( 'change', function () {
                var val = $(this).val();

                dtable.column( i )    //returns undefined
                    .search( val ? '^'+$(this).val()+'$' : val, true, false )
                    .draw(); 
            } );

        dtable.column( i ).data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {   //returns undefined
            select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
        } ); 
} );
```

The second half of the code is taken from dataTables [website](http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html). I use version 1.9.4 but tested with 1.10.2 but in vain. Can someone suggest what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried switching to .DataTable (note the capital "D")?

In short, .dataTable still works but returns a different type of object than .DataTable.

http://datatables.net/faqs/#api

Comment: I chose to do it in a different way, so I cannot test your solution but might be useful for someone else.